# Nuxt3 - Environmental Variable not access in Pinia Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, runtime-error, nuxtjs3

I have one problem. I'm actually trying to access `BASE_URL` from env in Pinia store through nuxt `runtimeConfig` it gives an error **500 nuxt instance unavailable**

Here's the error image

[image]

One thing I want to point out is when I hard coded `BASE_URL` it works fine but when I trying to access `BASE_URL` from environmental variable It give an error.

**Here's my code**

Pinia Store

```js
// Pinia Store for Home Page
import { useRuntimeConfig } from '#app'

const BASE_URL = useRuntimeConfig().public.api_url

export const useHomeStore = defineStore('home-store', {
  state: () => ({
    homePageData: {}
  }),

  actions: {
    async getHomePageData() {
      this.homePageData = await $fetch(`${BASE_URL}/products`)
    }
  }
})
```

Nuxt Config

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      api_url: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you using the `v3.0.0` of Nuxt?

Comment: Yes I'm using `"nuxt": "3.0.0",`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it seems I understand the problem.

The main matter is that you don't have access to `useRuntimeConfig` function from outside a store.

The example:

`home-store.ts`

```
/**
 * BAD - outside store, not working
 */
const BASE_URL = useRuntimeConfig().public.api_url;

export const useHomeStore = defineStore('home-store', {
  state: () => ({
    homePageData: {},
  }),

  actions: {
    async getHomePageData() {
      /**
       * GOOD - inside store
       */
      const BASE_URL = useRuntimeConfig().public.api_url;
      console.log('BASE_URL HERE:', BASE_URL);
      this.homePageData = await $fetch(`${BASE_URL}/products`);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I hope they'll add this into documentation soon.

Comment: we need to write `useRuntimeConfig().public.api_url` everytime when we need it. What if we can store this in state i mean create a `base_url` property in state and assign the `useRuntimeConfig().public.api_url` and next time when we need `base_url`. we just need to type `this.base_url`. I don't know if it's work or not but we should give it a try

Comment: this is a solution that works, but I don't think it's the best. The ideal would be to set a variable and reuse it.